# change screen in kivy or kivymd with press button

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to change the screen by pressing the button and checking that the text box is not empty.
here is my kv file:

> test.kv:

```
ScreenManager:
id: sc_m
Screen:
    name: 'welcome'           
    MDLabel:
        text: 'WeLCOME'
        halign: 'center'
        font_style: 'H3'
        color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.8}
    MDTextField:
        id: textbox
        hint_text: "The text box should not be empty"
        text:""
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    MDRoundFlatIconButton:
        text: "OK"
        icon: "folder"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .3}
        on_press: app.callback()
    
Screen:
    name:'screen2'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'WeLCOME'
        halign: 'center'
        font_style: 'H3'
        color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.8}
```

and here is my python code:

> main.py:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class MainApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style="Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette="Cyan"
        return Builder.load_file('test.kv')
    
    def callback(self):
        text = self.root.ids.textbox.text
        if len(text)==0:
            print('The text box should not be empty')
        else:
            self.root.ids.sc_m.current='screen2'


    
MainApp().run()
```

And the error i have:

> error:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

please help me!

Please do not read the rest of the article
I do not know what to say anymore because it gets an error when posting!
'''It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.'''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
self.root.ids.sc_m.current='screen2'
```

is trying to use an `id` that does not exist. You cannot make an `ids` entry for the root object of a rule (the `ids` only includes lower level widgets). But, since the `ScreenManager` is the root widget, you don't need to access it using `ids` anyway. Just replace the above code with:

```
self.root.current = 'screen2'
```